# Mutate column based on any lagged value of other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm having some issue with what I think should have been a pretty straightforward data transformation task.
I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df
  council_name year treat
1    Southwark 2008     1
2    Southwark 2009     0
3    Southwark 2010     1
4      Lambeth 2006     0
5      Lambeth 2007     1
6      Lambeth 2008     0
7    Yorkshire 2006     0
8    Yorkshire 2007     0
9    Yorkshire 2008     0
```

I'm trying to get a new variable say `pre.post` that takes the value `1` if a council has had, at any lower value of `year`, `1` for `treat`. Basically I want `pre.post == 1` if the `council` has had at any previous `year` `treat == 1`.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
df.desired
  council_name year treat pre.post
1    Southwark 2008     1        1
2    Southwark 2009     0        1
3    Southwark 2010     1        1
4      Lambeth 2006     0        0
5      Lambeth 2007     1        1
6      Lambeth 2008     0        1
7    Yorkshire 2006     0        0
8    Yorkshire 2007     0        0
9    Yorkshire 2008     0        0
```

Where basically all council that had at any *previous* time treat == 1 get pre.post == 1.
I tried different things like:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
group_by(council_name)%>%
arrange(year)%>%
mutate(pre.post = ifelse(any(lag(year) = 1), 1, 0))
```

But nothing seems to get exactly what I'm looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalently, find the first treatment year and assign 1 to every year after it.

```
df %>% group_by(council_name) %>% mutate(pre.post = +(year >= min(year[treat == 1])))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   council_name [3]
  council_name  year treat pre.post
  <chr>        <int> <int>    <int>
1 Southwark     2008     1        1
2 Southwark     2009     0        1
3 Southwark     2010     1        1
4 Lambeth       2006     0        0
5 Lambeth       2007     1        1
6 Lambeth       2008     0        1
7 Yorkshire     2006     0        0
8 Yorkshire     2007     0        0
9 Yorkshire     2008     0        0
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `pre.post`.
i no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
i Input `pre.post` is `+(year >= min(year[treat == 1]))`.
i The error occurred in group 3: council_name = "Yorkshire". 
2: In min(year[treat == 1]) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

We get this warning message as we are comparing something to `min(integer())`, which is set to be `Inf`. IMO, you can just ignore it as such comparison does not break our logic.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not working for me, I get the following error: 
Problem with `mutate()` input `pre.post`.
ℹ no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
ℹ Input `pre.post` is `+(year >= min(year[treat == 1]))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 46: code.fct = "E06000047".no non-missing arguments to min; returning

Comment: code.fct is the equivalent to the council_name variable in the example above

Comment: Are you sure it's an error? I think it's just a warning message that is the same as what I showed above. It doesn't matter. You should get the result even with that message. @AntVal

Comment: You're right, it does the trick anyways. Sorry! and thank you so much!